# SYNTAX error near SELECT

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ATTENDANCE = 
            "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_ATTENDANCE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ATTENDANCEID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_ATTENDANCEEVENTID + " INTEGER, " +
                    KEY_ATTENDANCEEVENTCOUNT + "INTEGER, " +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(attendanceevent) REFERENCES Purchases_Table(purchaseevent)," +
                    " SELECT * SUM(ticketquantity) AS TOTAL FROM Purchases_Table GROUP BY eventid" + ")";
```

I keep getting a syntax error in this particular table near the SELECT FUNCTION. Its for my sqlite database.

Comment: Why are you performing a SELECT operation during the table's creation?

Comment: I basically want to catch how many tickets get sold per event. I thought thats how you do it.

Comment: use create table and select statements separately

Comment: Is that select statement correct?

Comment: The select statement seems to be correct (apart the *), but I have never seen the usage of the select along with a create table.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be **Select SUM(ticketquantity)...** instead of **Select * SUM(ticketquantity)**

Comment: Alrighty, how do I call it in the database? Was what I did alright doing it in the create table?

Comment: You should use Select and Create table statements one at a time.

Comment: I've tried your answer and still comes up with syntax error. How do i make them separate? Sorry to hassle

Comment: Create two different final string variables. One for Creating table, and another for selecting ticketQuantity

Comment: so will it be like : public static final String "SELECT SUM(ticket quantity) AS TOTAL FROM Purchases_Table eventid";